# I cannot connect with public key authenticated SSH connection to a server, the connection just gets... dropped

Tags: networking, ssh

I set up my SSH server to accept connections with public key authentication, for the group `myGroup`. I created a user on the server inside this group, called `myUser`. Then I generated the key pair on the server, put the public key into the `/home/myUser/.ssh/authorized_keys` folder, restarted `sshd`, then tried to connect from a remote machine with this user and my private key file:

```
ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa myUser@<server_address> -vvv
```

The authentication is successful, but then the connection is immediately dropped:

```
...
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /tmp/testing/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 5f:8e:29:80:22:3c:c5:e9:48:42:b1:3e:57:e0:c3:f5
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <server_address> ([<server_address>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

As you can see, the public key authentication worked, but then I got `Write failed: Broken pipe`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if you specified a `Chroot` in your sftp settings, that folder must be owned by root and have `755` permissions **exactly**.